# Are dependents (such as children) taken into account before applying a hadd punishment?

Tags: punishment, children, hudud

Applying a [hadd punishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudud), such as the death penalty or amputation, obviously either eliminates or greatly diminishes a person's earning potential.  This is problematic when this person has dependents (children to house, clothe, feed, etc., and also wives).

**Question**: Are dependents taken into account before applying a hadd punishment?

I've never seen anything that talks about mitigating factors for hadd punishments.  I'm aware of his verse which suggests we should not "edit" the divine laws:

> [Say], "Then is it other than Allah I should seek as judge while it is He who has revealed to you the Book explained in detail?" And those to whom We [previously] gave the Scripture know that it is sent down from your Lord in truth, so never be among the doubters.
>   <sub>[Qur'an 6:114](https://quran.com/6/114)</sub>

Comment: I know there were cases of Muslim women being sentenced to death in countries with Shariah-based legal systems (e.g. [Nigeria](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/africaandindianocean/nigeria/1360795/Nigerian-woman-is-sentenced-to-death-by-stoning.html), [Sudan](https://www.cnn.com/2014/05/15/world/africa/sudan-christian-woman-apostasy/index.html)), but having the execution stayed until after their child was weaned . Can't speak for the Islamic basis (if any) for the rulings though, or how it would apply to other cases.

Comment: @goldPseudo As for Islamic basis, there's that hadith where a woman comes to Muhammad demanding she be stoned for adultery, and he sends her off a bunch because she's pregnant at first, then the baby needs to be weaned, maybe that's relevant to those cases?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but on a case-by-case basis.

From the long hadith narrated on the authority of 'Abdullah ibn Buraida, the Prophet ﷺ delayed the stoning of a woman from Ghāmid till after her child had weaned:

> قَالَ: إِمَّا لاَ فَاذْهَبِي حَتَّى تَلِدِي.‏ فَلَمَّا وَلَدَتْ أَتَتْهُ بِالصَّبِيِّ فِي خِرْقَةٍ قَالَتْ هَذَا قَدْ وَلَدْتُهُ.‏ قَالَ: ‏ اذْهَبِي فَأَرْضِعِيهِ حَتَّى تَفْطِمِيهِ.‏ فَلَمَّا فَطَمَتْهُ أَتَتْهُ بِالصَّبِيِّ فِي يَدِهِ كِسْرَةُ خُبْزٍ فَقَالَتْ هَذَا يَا نَبِيَّ اللَّهِ قَدْ فَطَمْتُهُ وَقَدْ أَكَلَ الطَّعَامَ.‏ فَدَفَعَ الصَّبِيَّ إِلَى رَجُلٍ مِنَ الْمُسْلِمِينَ ثُمَّ أَمَرَ بِهَا فَحُفِرَ لَهَا إِلَى صَدْرِهَا وَأَمَرَ النَّاسَ فَرَجَمُوهَا
>
> He said: "Well, if you insist upon it, then go away until you give birth to (the child)." When she was delivered she came with the child (wrapped) in a rag and said: "Here is the child whom I have given birth to." He said: "Go away and suckle him until you wean him." When she had weaned him, she came to him (the Holy Prophet) with the child who was holding a piece of bread in his hand. She said: "Allah's Apostle, here is he as I have weaned him and he eats food." He (the Holy Prophet) entrusted the child to one of the Muslims and then pronounced the punishment. And she was put in a ditch up to her chest and he commanded people and they stoned her.
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 29, Hadith 35](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/29/35)</sub>

In *Mawsū'at al-Fiqh al-Islāmi*
[5/110](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32292/2982) (Arabic only),
Mohammad ibn Ibrahim at-Tuwaijri dedicated a section to the possible causes of delaying the fulfillment of a *hadd* punishment as:

- What is related to the process of conducting the *hadd* punishment (e.g., weather, illness, etc.), which is also mentioned in *Bahr al-Madhhab* [13/20](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33140/6256#p1) (Shafi'i, Arabic only).
- What is related to the persons upon whom the *hadd* punishment is to be conducted (e.g., pregnancy, breastfeeding, etc.), which is also mentioned in *Qawā'id Ibn Rajab* [3/225](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33191/830#p1) (Hanbali, Arabic only).

I do not know of a comprehensive list of all potential causes for delay, though.